# trait for something generic, but errors could be specific for trait implementation

Tags: rust

Let's say I have a trait for a `Decoder`, and I have specific decoders that implement this trait:

```
pub trait Decoder {
    fn do_something(&self) -> Result<(), DoSomethingError>;
}

pub enum DoSomethingError {}

pub struct SpecificDecoder1 {}

impl Decoder for SpecificDecoder1 {
    fn do_something(&self) -> Result<(), DoSomethingError> {
        todo!()
    }
}

pub struct SpecificDecoder2 {}

impl Decoder for SpecificDecoder2 {
    fn do_something(&self) -> Result<(), DoSomethingError> {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

each decoder could return specific errors. However, I don't want to include these specific errors in the `DoSomethingError` trait as some decoders could not even be available on some devices, so I don't want the mess of `#cfg(feature="...")` on the enum.

I thought about

```
pub trait DoSomethingError {}
fn do_something(&self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn DoSomethingError>> {
    Ok(self.do_another_something()?)
}
```

this way I can downcast the `Box<dyn DoSomethingError>` to a specific error if needed. However, `Ok(self.do_another_something()?)` wouldn't work. Remember that I don't want to store a string, I want to be able to match the error somehow, or try to match it, so I cannot create a `UserDefined(String)` variant on the string and convert every error to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a different Error for each implementation, you can define the trait with an associated error type, just like in [TryFrom](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html):

```rust
pub trait Decoder {
    type Error;
    fn do_something(&self) -> Result<(), Self::Error>;
}

pub enum SpecificDecoder1Error {}
pub struct SpecificDecoder1 {}
impl Decoder for SpecificDecoder1 {
    type Error = SpecificDecoder1Error;
    fn do_something(&self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> {
        todo!()
    }
}

pub enum SpecificDecoder2Error {}
pub struct SpecificDecoder2 {}
impl Decoder for SpecificDecoder2 {
    type Error = SpecificDecoder2Error;
    fn do_something(&self) -> Result<(), Self::Error> {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

But if you want the trait to return a generic type, you can return a `dyn` [std::any::Any](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) value, and downcast if necessary:

```rust
pub trait Decoder {
    fn do_something(&self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::any::Any>>;
}

pub struct SpecificDecoder1Error(u16);
pub struct SpecificDecoder1 {}
impl Decoder for SpecificDecoder1 {
    fn do_something(&self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::any::Any>> {
        Err(Box::new(SpecificDecoder1Error(13)))
    }
}

pub struct SpecificDecoder2Error(String);
pub struct SpecificDecoder2 {}
impl Decoder for SpecificDecoder2 {
    fn do_something(&self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::any::Any>> {
        Err(Box::new(SpecificDecoder2Error(
            "Specific Error 2".to_string(),
        )))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let dec1 = SpecificDecoder1 {};
    let dec2 = SpecificDecoder2 {};
    let decs: [&dyn Decoder; 2] = [&dec1, &dec2];
    for dec in decs {
        let error = dec.do_something().err().unwrap();
        if let Some(error1) = error.downcast_ref::<SpecificDecoder1Error>() {
            println!("Error from SpecificDecoder1Error: {}", error1.0)
        } else if let Some(error2) =
            error.downcast_ref::<SpecificDecoder2Error>()
        {
            println!("Error from SpecificDecoder2Error: {}", error2.0)
        } else {
            unreachable!()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my concern was about using `?` on the `dyn Any`. Creating error boxes all the time out be bad. Do you think there's a nice way of not needing to create a box every time?

Comment: Yes, avoiding using box when unnecessary is a good idea. But it depends a lot about the citation. Usually errors are returned only once, because lots of times when they happen, the program abort it's execution/task, so maybe in you case is not a big deal.